# Angular version dispalyed in vendor.js

Tags: html, angularjs, gruntjs, xss, cross-site

A security audit was conducted for the UI that was developed. In the audit, the following is mentioned

" The assessed application was discovered to be running non-current third-party JavaScript libraries with known XSS vulnerabilities.

It was possible to identify Angularjs version 1.5.0 on the web application, which is known to contain vulnerabilities. The version was identified from the following HTTP response: (Screenshot attached below) The references section provides more information on the specific attacks, however the version presented can provide a Cross Site Scripting or Content Security Policy bypass route."

[image: ![The following is the screen shot]][1](https://i.stack.imgur.com/boUGd.png)

When I checked in the application it comes int vendor..js. This is generated as part of grunt build. We don't have control to this file. Can someone help me how to resolve the issue

Regards

Viji

Comment: use a different version or download it, host it locally and edit it there.

Comment: Sorry i could not understand. Different version of angular ?

Comment: Hi @LW001  Please can you explain. Sorry i have very less time to complete this.

Comment: If you don't have access to the grunt build, then how would you be able to do anything about which version of angular grunt is including?  It's not really clear what you are expecting here....  It seems like this isn't a problem that can be solved here, but something that should be solved by whoever developed your UI.

Comment: Hi @Claies Sorry may be i was not clear on what i meant as access. I have access to the grunt file. We are using bower.json for all the version dependencies and using grunt build to build the app.

Comment: ok so are you just asking how to update your bower file to use a newer version of the angular dependency?  You didn't even tag [tag:bower] in the question......

Answer (score 0):

The issue reported was different. The issue about the vulnerable versions.
Referred this link for my better understanding.

https://snyk.io/vuln/npm:angular

Regards
Viji